# java.lang.LinkageError: MainActivity

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-multidex

I use `productFlavours` in my app. 
I'm also using multi dex.

```
 defaultConfig {
         multiDexEnabled true
         minSdkVersion 17
         targetSdkVersion 22
         ... 
 }

productFlavors {
  prodFlavor1{...}
  prodFlavor2{...}
 }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
...
}
```

In the Application class:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        MultiDex.install(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate();
}
```

I have added the above code for Android versions below 5 support.

Then the following structure, with 2 slightly different versions of `MainActivity` (MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity) starts at a certain moment in the app, on a button press.

```
app/src/prodFlavor1/.../MainActivity
app/src/prodFlavor2/.../MainActivity
```

In `prodFlavor1`, `MainActivity` starts immediately after `SplashActivity`.
In `prodFlavor2`, `MainActivity`.

This worked for a long period before and even after I added that part with `multidex`, but suddenly stooped working with no explanation. Even if I remove the code referencing multidex, I get the same thing.

When I switch to `prodVersion2` everything works. But when I switch to `prodVersion1` I get:

`startActivity(new Intent(TutorialActivity.this,MainActivity.class));`

**Nexus 5 with Android 6:**

```
Process: com.mpackage, PID: 30807
                                                             java.lang.LinkageError: com.mpackage.activities.MainActivity
                                                                 at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:338)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                 at com.gossip.activities.TutorialActivity$1.handleMessage(TutorialActivity.java:52)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**On Nexus4 Emulator with Android 4.4:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mpackage.activities.MainActivity
                                                               at com.gossip.activities.TutorialActivity$1.handleMessage(TutorialActivity.java:52)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE:**

Seems that the error was caused by the fact that I have added a method called `isResumed()` in `MainActivity`, that's why `(Native Method)` error, different on 6.0 from 4.4.

Answer (score 22):

Finally solved after found [this](https://github.com/xiprox/ErrorView/issues/5) useful thread:

I have created a method `isResumed()` in my class.

```
public boolean isResumed(){
    return isResumed;
}
```

Immediate after I removed/edit it everything went to normal. I didn't find this method in `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity` in the documentation.

Comment: It is hidden in the documentation, yes (see @hide). But you can find it in the source code: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L6432

Comment: Good old fashioned Android fun.

Comment: Incredible, thanks for this one. Three years later, I had the same issue in Kotlin: `var isResumed: Boolean`

Comment: @Mario huizinga did you get any solution? I am getting same issue

Comment: @KhyatiChitroda Just use a different name for your var

Answer (score 1):

Conflicting name of function with one of base classes. Rename your function to something custom i.e. isBaseResumed()